# CSS nesting rules on same class tag

Tags: html, css, nested

I have two css styles, the second of which I only want to take effect when the first is present. How would I go about that? I know that you can add more than one class to a class tag, but it doesn't seem to work to nest the css tags the same way.

```
.stat{float: left; width: 200px; height: 40px; padding: 5px; margin: 5px; border: 1px solid #000;}
.stat .red{background-color: #c00;}


<!-- This should have the background color -->
<div class="stat red">

<!-- This should not have the background color -->
<div class="red">

<!-- This should not have the background color -->
<div class="stat">
```

Comment: `.stat.red` (no space)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just leave out the space:

```
.stat.red{background-color: #c00;}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for clarification

```
.stat .red { ... }
```

or more precisely the " " between the classnames, is called a descendant selector. In your case it means that only elements with class "red", that are **descendants** of elements with class "stat" will be targeted. e.g.

```
<div class="stat">
   <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the .stat.red selector called?

Comment: `.xyz` is called class selector, just containing multiple classes in your case.